# Is CiviCRM a good choice for a website front end AND membership management?

Tags: workflow, administer

We are looking for a CMS (or similar) for our Big Band.  We need

1. A page for the public to see our next gigs
2. Membership management to keep a list of band members, deputies;
3. An events calendar diary for rehearsals and gigs;
4. A file store so that PDFs of our set lists,  music charts etc can be stored and available for all band members;

It's clear to me that CiviCRM would be fine for 2 & 3, but not so clear that it will also cover items 1 & 4.

Any thoughts/help appreciated.
Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to the community.

In short:

Q1. & Q2. are easily met with CiviCRM.

Q3. Can be done with a little effort.

Q4. This would be provided by your Content Management System (CMS). CiviCRM works with Drupal, WordPress, and Joomla!. For this, I'd go with Drupal (with which you could do this through configuration), but this functionality may also be provided by Joomla! and WordPress plugins.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did numbers get mixed up here @johnff? Answer says 1,2 are easily met and 2 takes a little effort.

Comment: @ChrisBurgess yes well spotted. Amending now, thanks for the assist.

Comment: @ChrisBurgess actually no (when I hit edit it was correct as when I wrote it. It seems that the formatting changes them! Bizarre.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

**For item #4 ->** When you run CiviCRM on Drupal it comes with this module:

CiviMember Roles Sync - Synchronize CiviCRM Contacts with Membership Status to a specified Drupal Role automatically.

In a nutshell - here's how this works: someone Logs in -> Drupal checks with CiviCRM -> ah this person has Membership A + status = Current; Drupal checks your Rules -> ah that means this user should get Role = Member A -> so that user now automatically has all the permissions (and thus buttons) that Member A should have.

This is how you can make really slick Member only content/sections on your CMS/website!

Comment: That helps me make the choice on CMS - I use Joomla in work, but sounds like Drupal is the way to go here.

Comment: For completeness, WordPress also has the ability to sync roles with CiviCRM. If you're **sure** you won't be needing to customize any Views or Webforms, WP is a good choice. Otherwise Drupal is the most powerful of the 3.

Comment: Pretty sure all three CMSes offer this ability, Joomla included. I actually prefer Joomla's ACL over WP, though I can't speak to Drupal.

Comment: On CMS integration Drupal is head and shoulders above above the other CMSs